# Testing react component that receives methods from other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I made some research but not found how to test component shallow rendering that receives functions from other components in props. I'm using Enzyme.

If it's just data, I can test with: `const wrapper = shallow(<Component prop1="data" />)`, but if it's methods from a parent component?

Answer (score 0):

You could mock your function and check whether the method has been called. Jest provides an easy way to do this by using `jest.fn()`. First create your mock

```
const mockCallback = jest.fn();
```

Then shallow render your component passing the function. For instance

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component prop1={mockCallback} />)
```

Use the find selector to get the component you want and simulate a change or a click

```
wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
```

And finally check if the function was called

```
expect(mockCallback.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

Comment: I don't understand how the first line `const mockCallback = jest.fn();` will get the function passed from the parent to the component being tested, can you explain to me?

Comment: The function it's just a mock. The test above will check if your component being tested calls the function when it is needed. Since the function being passes as prop does not concern the component being tested we just need to check if the function was called. If you want to test if the function works as intended you have to test the parent component, not the child. If you use the parent function to test the child (mixing the tests) and the tests fails you will not be able to tell (easily) if the problem is inside your component or the parent